# Pyspark 3.1.1 direct streaming with kafka?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Pyspark 2.4.7 contains the ability to create a direct stream listener to a kafka topic ([documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html))

However, the 3.1.1 (latest) version of pyspark doesn't have this feature. And the [latest documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html) for kafka direct streaming doesn't include python examples anymore.

My question is how to use direct streaming (not structured streaming) with kafka and pyspark 3.1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kafka 0.8 support is deprecated as of Spark 2.3.0.

spark-streaming-kafka-0-8 has language support for Scala, Java, Python but spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 does not support Python.

Please refer the below link

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/streaming-kafka-integration.html